# How to get image manipulation url from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to have an image server on Google Cloud Storage. Currently I'm using Cloudinary, and I can easily manipulate the image size by passing the parameter within the URL.

How do I achieve this in Google Cloud Storage ?

Thank you,
Wiljon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not intrinsically support an image resize mechanism. Google AppEngine's Images API ([Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/), [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/), [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/images/)) has various serving URL accessors that then take resizing options, but requires the AppEngine application outlive the URL.